# Quantify Diminishing Returns or Linear Regression or Other?

Tags: python, math, non-linear-regression

Semi math related question here, but I believe it is still valid since it is something I am working on in Python. Plus, the MathOverflow people would laugh at my feeble mind.

Anyways, I have a real estate related project I am working on. In the below example, I have 5 properties with their square footage and price per square foot. This example illustrates there is a slight diminishing returns in real estate. Specifically, when all else is equal, the higher the square footage becomes, the lower the price per square foot becomes.

How can I create an equation to be used in Python that best takes this into account so I can easily plug in a square footage and based on this data get an accurate estimate of the price per square footage for F(x).

[image]

Comment: This looks like house predicting problem have you tried `scikit` machine learning?

Comment: I've looked into it briefly. I am not super familiar with machine learning. This problem seems much more basic to me, does it really require something like scikit? If so, are you able to point me in the right direction. There is a ton of content on scikit.

Answer (score 0):

Machine learning is not necessary.

You can do this with a simple linear regression.  You can even get it right out of Excel by plotting the data and asking for the appropriate fitting equation to be shown.

Here's what I get when I ask Excel to plot and fit your data.  The solid line is your data; the dotted line is the 2nd order polynomial that Excel generated using linear regression.  The equation is small, but you should be able to read it if you enlarge the image.

[image]